# In spring-boot, is it possible to get properties without being a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Configuration.class, which fetches properties from `application.properties`.

```
@Component
public class Configuration {

    @Value("${someValue}")
    public String someValue;
}
```

I have another class called `Fetcher`, which needs the property.

```
class Fetcher {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    public void doSomethingWithSomeValue() {
        System.out.println(configuration.someValue);
    }
}
```

Of course the above code would fail because `Fetcher` is not a Spring Bean(I didn't add `@Component`/`@Service`/`@Repository` to it). My question is, is it possible to get `someValue` in `Fetcher` without making it a Spring Bean?

Comment: maybe, reading the configuration file into a map and fetch it from there?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/18486178/1032167  and https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and yes.

No is because that's the whole idea of Spring and dependency injection. You have to use something which will have access to Spring ApplicationContext.

Yes, because you may use publish–subscribe pattern, or you may make some of your context aware beans to be a singleton, and let them expose all the necessary properties. But it is just delegation to object which has access to Spring context. To make an analogy: it is not the crime, it is just selling weapon and giving money to someone who will make an actual shot :)