# Error starting ApplicationContext in docker

Tags: spring-boot, applicationcontext

My program works fine when running it from IntelliJ IDE, but when I'm using it from a docker file it gives this error:

```
 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
 2020-03-26 13:48:35.598 ERROR 19 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Which will consequently throw a nullPointerException and can't get the beans.

I have defined the following class

```java
    @Component
    public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private static ApplicationContext ctx;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)throws BeansException {
            ctx = appContext;

        }

        public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
                 return ctx;
        }
    }
```

And on my RabbitMQ I do:

```java
    ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();
    FirebaseMessage firebaseMessage =  appCtx.getBean(FirebaseMessage.class);
    RabbitMQRequester rabbitMQRequester = appCtx.getBean(RabbitMQRequester.class);
```

I don't get why it works on the IDE and not on the docker-compose with a docker file build

Comment: You shouldn't use that util class. You should use dependency injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had to use that because I ran into this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550899/nullpointerexception-autowired-mongodb-collection which I resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347518/spring-autowiring-not-working-from-a-non-spring-managed-class/18486178#18486178

Comment: The problem is you are trying to inject things into non-managed instances. And as there is no guarantee on the order that can be problematic. Just do proper injection and you don't need this ugly hack and things will work.

Comment: How do you suggest that I do that injection?

Comment: By making that rabbitmq class a spring managed bean and not created outside the scope of Spring with `new`. More clarification was asked on your original question but instead of extending that question you lead to a path using this hack (which it really is).

Comment: Well I'm not doing a new. I'm making it a @Component. Firebase and RabbitRequester are also a Component
I did this because of this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null#comment41516309_19896871

Comment: The fact that it is a component doesn't mean you are nowhere not creating an instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok. This is going to sound stupid, but I used Autowired notation for that and it didn't work. But now I tried again and everything is fine. Thanks for your hints.